# what is the value of $\sum\limits_{x \in P_n \cap W} 1$?

Tags: measure-theory

In Rudin RCA  theorem $2.20$ Page no : $51$ it is written that

If $f$ is any complex function on $R^k$, with  compact support i,e  $f(x) \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^k)$ ,define

$$\Lambda_n f :=  2^{-nk} \sum\limits_{x \in P_n} f(x)$$
where $P_n$ is the set of all vectors of the form $x = (a_1/2^n,...,a_k/2^n)$ for $a_1,...,a_k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

My question is that   what is the value  of $\sum\limits_{x \in P_n}1?$

My attempt : Take an open set $W$ i,e $W$ an open $k-$cell for which  supp$(f) \subset W$.Then

$$\Lambda_n f :=  2^{-nk} \sum\limits_{x \in P_n} f(x)=2^{-nk} \sum\limits_{x \in P_n \cap W} f(x)+2^{-nk} \sum\limits_{x \in P_n , x \notin\ W}f(x)$$

Since  support is compact  so $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in P_n \cap W$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in P_n \setminus W$

Therefore $$\Lambda_n f :=  2^{-nk} \sum\limits_{x \in P_n} f(x)=2^{-nk} \sum\limits_{x \in P_n \cap W} f(x)+0=2^{-nk} \sum\limits_{x \in P_n \cap W} 1+0$$

Here im confused  that  what is the value  of $\sum\limits_{x \in P_n \cap W} 1$?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{x \in P_n \cap W} 1 = | P_n \cap W|$

Comment: @Henry im not getting   why you put mod ? I'm talking about summation

Comment: @Henry $|P_n \cap W|$  denote the  cardinality of $P_n \cap W$  Am i right ?

Comment: @jasmine: Right.  If you add up 1 for every element of $P_n \cap W$, you get the number of elements in $P_n \cap W$, i.e. its cardinality if it is finite, or $+\infty$ if it is infinite.